# How do I use the synchronize function from mixer

Tags: java, audio, javasound, mixer

I'm creating a program which mathematically generates byte arrays that are interpreted into sound, and to make them all play at the same rate and begin on the same sample, I need to use the `Mixer` interface from `java.sound.sampled`, and more specifically, the `synchronize(line[], boolean maintainSync)`. I have it set as:

```
 Mixer a = (Mixer) new Object();
        a.synchronize(lines, false);
        lines[0].start();
```

I know this code doesn't work, but neither does implementing the interface into my class and trying to refer to the method through `this.synchronize(----)` but the class needs to become `abstract` in order to implement it due to a `line.getInfo` function. *I don't know how to use the `synchronize()` method without encountering a problem or making the function actually work*.